# Separating Axis Theorem in Python/Pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, collision-detection, pyglet

I'm trying to make a (sort-of) clone of Asteroids in Python using Pyglet. I figured I'd try to get a little fancy and implement the separating axis theorem to do collision. I got it to work, but the problem is that it's miserably slow. I test collision between bullets that the player shoots and the asteroids on the screen in a double for-loop, which I believe is quadratic time, but the frame rate drops from about 60 to 30 fps by the time there's about 6 asteroids and 6 bullets on the screen, which seems incredibly slow, even for a non-optimized way of detecting collision.

So I ran a profiler to determine where, exactly, in the code the program is getting hung up. It seems to be hung up in the method where I transform shape vertices into world space (I define the shapes around the origin and use OpenGL code to transform to world space for drawing, which I believe is the right way to do it). I grab the transformation matrix from OpenGL, turn it into a NumPy array, and then multiply each vertex by this matrix to get the transformed vertices. It's worth noting that I do this every collision check: I used to use XNA, and when I implemented the SAT in that (I made an asteroids clone there, too), the vertices were also defined around the origin and then you had to transform them using a world matrix.

Is it best to store the vertices around (0, 0) and transform each call, or just store the transformed vertices? I feel like the algorithm shouldn't be THIS slow, so I'm willing to bet I screwed up implementing something. If I was better at profiling (I'm pretty unfamiliar with it) I might be able to get a more complete picture, but I was hoping you guys might have some idea.

Here's a direct link to the file with the Shape class in it, where all the collision logic happens: [shape.py](https://github.com/Cheeser12/pysteroids/blob/master/lib/geometry/shape.py). The specific method that the profiler seemed to mark as the bottleneck was __get_transformed_verts. Obviously you can get to the entire repo from there too, but just be aware that there's still a good deal not commented.

Comment: How many vertices do your meshes have? A way to extremely improve performance is to check for collision with a simpler geometry (e.g. two bounding spheres) at first.

Comment: The bullets are 4 verts (squares) and the asteroids are 9 verts right now. I will take your suggestion and do a sphere test first, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nico suggests in comments, a quick way to get a good speed-up would be to check simpler geometry first. For an Asteroids clone I guess a circle will be a good fit (or sphere for 3D). If the circles (at least large enough to cover your actual shape) don't overlap, then there is no need to do the more expensive geometry test.

If you have many objects, you will probably want to avoid doing n*n tests every frame. Take a look at space partitioning structures/algorithms. The simplest scheme with a lot of moving objects in 2D would be a grid. Then you only need to test objects belonging to the same - or neighbouring - grid cells for collision.

Another thing I noticed: You generate the transformed vertices every time you test for collision. It would be quicker to generate them only once per timestep (frame) for each object that fails the circle-circle test.

Comment: I'll try using bounding circles as a first test, and I'll look into some space partitioning algorithms too, thanks. I've heard of something called quadtrees for 2D, but maybe a regular grid will suffice?

Comment: I think you'll see a big speed up with bounding circles. You might not need any kind of space partitioning unless you're going to increase the number of objects which need to be tested. Yes quadtrees are another option. Look also at "loose" quadtrees/octrees. They're good for dynamic scenes because you can insert objects into the tree very quickly.